# Statistical comparison between two maps with aggregated average observations and average estimates from a model on a 1 x 1 km² grid

Tags: qgis, python, geometry, spatial-statistics, comparison

I've been searching for methods for the past two days, but I couldn't find something usefull, so I hope someone could help me out:

I've got two datasets in python containing PM2.5 values:

1. Dataset which consists of hourly estimated values done by a model for a geographical location on a 1 x 1 km² spatial resolution
2. Dataset that contains low cost sensor observations for the same geographical location as point values

I want to analyze the difference between te observed values and the estimated values from the model on a daily scale (daily averages per 1 x 1 km² grid).

Thus far I created a vector grid of 1 x 1 km², aggregated all daily observations within the grids and assigned the daily averages to the grids (full code found here: https://github.com/ibatoukhtine/PM2.5/blob/main/PM25%20analysis.ipynb). I've done this for both the estimated values and the sensor observations.

Now I want to do an analysis between the two, but I'm stuck in what is possible for this comparison. Is it just as easy as creating a map which shows the mean difference per grid cell? For example, Grid_estimates - Grid_observations = Grid_difference? This will tell me if the model is overestimating or underestimating at certain locations, however I also still need to say something about the uncertainty of the grid cells depending on the amount of unique sensor contributed values to the daily average for the grid cells (maybe a CI?)